# Laravel query result is protected?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand what Laravel is doing here. All I'm trying to do is get five random instances of my model:

```
$players = User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(5)->get();
```

If I `var_dump()` this variable, I see a lot of useless attributes and what I'm interested is protected so I can't even access it. Here's an extract:

```
["table":protected]=> string(5) "users"
["hidden":protected]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(8) "password"
}
["connection":protected]=> NULL
["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id"
["perPage":protected]=> int(15)
["incrementing"]=> bool(true)
["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use getters. What exactly do you need?

Comment: All I need is the name and id.

Comment: `foreach($players as $player) { $player->name; $player->id; }` is what you need, right?

Comment: In the view yes, but I first need to get the data in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$players->toArray();
```

will give you the result in array format.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

$players is a Laravel collection. You can iterate over it

```
foreach($players as $player)
{
    echo $player->name;
}
```

You can access unique items using array syntax

```
$player = $players[0];

echo $player->name;
```

You can filter them

```
$players = $players->filter(function($item, $key)
{
    return $item->name !== 'Bad player";
});
```

And alot more (including `toArray()` and `toJson()`).

To answer your question. Don't turn it into an array if you're passing it to a view. Just pass the entire collection as a variable and in your blade markup you would have something like this:

```
@foreach($players as $player)
    <li data-id="{{$player->id}}">{{$player->name}}</li>
@endforeach
```